# Calendar precision skew while parsing a postgresql timestamp with time zone

Tags: java, postgresql, calendar

I noticed a bug while converting a postgresql **datetime with time zone**

```
SimpleDateFormat postgreSQLTimestampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX");

Calendar inst = Calendar.getInstance();
inst.setTime(postgreSQLTimestampFormat.parse("2014-11-13 17:36:41.936208+01"));

logger.info(activationChangeDate + " -> " + inst.getTimeInMillis());
```

according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html the format should be correct, but the output is:

> 2014-11-13 17:36:41.936208+01 -> 1415897537208

and converting the timestamp 1415897537 (truncating the 3 millis digits) in GMT+1 returns

> 2014-11-13T17:52:17+01:00

there is a skew of 7 minutes, and cannot wonder why.

Converting back to another format doesn't help either:

```
SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm.ss");
logger.info(outFormat.format(inst.getTimeInMillis()));
```

reflects the skew:

> 13/11/2014 17:52.17

===
EDIT
doing more tests it seems that SimpleDateFormat (or Calendar for what I known) cannot handle microsenconds:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX");
    SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
    SimpleDateFormat format3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX");

    try {
        Calendar inst = Calendar.getInstance();
        inst.setTime(format1.parse("2014-11-13 17:36:41.936208+01"));
        System.out.println(inst.getTimeInMillis()); 
        // 1415897537208 -> 2014-11-13T17:52:17+01:00 [wrong]
        inst.setTime(format2.parse("2014-11-13 17:36:41.936+01"));
        System.out.println(inst.getTimeInMillis()); 
        // 1415896601936 -> 2014-11-13T17:36:41+01:00 [good]
        inst.setTime(format3.parse("2014-11-13 17:36:41+01")); 
        System.out.println(inst.getTimeInMillis()); 
        // 1415896601000 -> 2014-11-13T17:36:41+01:00 [good]
    } catch (ParseException e) {}
```

Looking for suggestion to overcome this.